# Unformatted string in new close-vote review queue format

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close

In the ***new*** review queue page, in the "This question has been flagged as" section, there is a header that shows up as "**subreason.InputTitle**"

[image]

I believe this is unintentional since that string doesn't seem to be very helpful.

Comment: @Glorfindel Done! https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361427/751520